# tinyMCE 4 instance after mceAddEditor really tall

Tags: tinymce-4

Pre-note: This issue occurs whether or not I already have a textarea on the page.

I have a button that triggers an ajax request first...writing something to a database and returning the key. I use that key in my ID for the textarea that is then dynamically added to page. Keep in mind that tinyMCE is already initialized.

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".editor",
        setup: function(ed) {
            ed.on('change', function(e) {
                tinymce.triggerSave();
                $('form').trigger('checkform.areYouSure');
            });
            ed.on('init', function(e) {
                autoresize_max_height: 500
            });
        },
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link responsivefilemanager lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "save table contextmenu directionality template paste textcolor colorpicker responsivefilemanager autoresize"
        ],
        toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | outdent indent | table | link responsivefilemanager",
        image_advtab: true ,

        external_filemanager_path:"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title:"Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
    });
```

After the textarea is dynamically created, I add some default 'Lorem Ipsum' text and call mceAddEditor

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, "custom-html_" + data.c2akey);
```

data.c2akey is the key returned from the ajax call.

The tinymce instance is created successfully.

**Here's the problem:**

1) The instance is super tall. Unless I set a static height on the parent container the textarea is, the editor is really tall. Taller than 500px (from **autoresize_max_height**). Problem with setting a static height on the parent container is that autoresize wont work. Also I dont see the text from the textarea in this new editor.

2) I can not type in this newly created instance. See [Can't type in tinyMCE 4 instance after mceAddEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737588/cant-type-in-tinymce-4-instance-after-mceaddeditor)

So I need help figuring out why the instance is super tall on creating.

Comment: If I choose not to add default text when I create my textarea dynamically, then the editor is a good height. Could have been an issue with my text being added.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem (The instance is super tall) I've solved as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
         $(editor.iframeElement)
                .contents()
                .find('body')
                .css('min-height', editor.targetElm.rows * 9);
    }
});
```